# React.JS select HTML heading tags rather than body for dark mode toggle feature

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, if-statement, toggle

I'm trying to add a dark mode feature and have been successful, the issue is that the toggle between dark/light mode is only targeting the body of the html/css

```css
   :root {
  --blue: rgb(13, 59, 105);
  --white: rgb(255, 254, 254);
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-weight);
}

body.light {
  --background-color: var(--white);
  --text-color: var(--blue);
  --image: url("./day-forrest.jpg");
}

body.dark {
  --background-color: var(--blue);
  --text-color: var(--white);
  --image: url("./night-forrest.jpg");
}

.title-heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4rem 0 0 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: var(--text-color);
}


nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background: var(--text-color);
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--background-color);
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1100px;
  background-image: var(--image);
}

.title-heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4rem 0 1rem 0;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.subtitle {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

```
const DarkMode = () => {
  let clickedClass = "clicked";
  const body = document.body;
  const lightMode = "light";
  const darkMode = "dark";
  let theme;

  if (localStorage) {
    theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  }

  if (theme === lightMode || theme === darkMode) {
    body.classList.add(theme);
  } else {
    body.classList.add(lightMode);
  }

  const switchTheme = (e) => {
    if (theme === darkMode) {
      body.classList.replace(darkMode, lightMode);
      e.target.classList.remove(clickedClass);
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
      theme = lightMode;
    } else {
      body.classList.replace(lightMode, darkMode);
      e.target.classList.add(clickedClass);
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
      theme = darkMode;
    }
  };

  return (
    <button
      className={theme === "dark" ? clickedClass : ""}
      id="darkMode"
      onClick={(e) => switchTheme(e)}
    ></button>
  );
};

export default DarkMode;
```

A solution for this problem would be to have 3 separate heading colors of work experience, Hobbies and Contact in light mode and for them to all turn to white in dark mode rather than only having the 2 changeable color options of blue and white throughout the whole page.

--blue: rgb(13, 59, 105);
--white: rgb(255, 254, 254);

thanks in advance the sandbox link is here https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-mode-issue-14-11-22-f0edup?file=/src/AboutPage/styles.css

Comment: In the live demo it looks like everything is switching color mode smoothly. What is the desired result here if you won't mind to specify a bit more?

Comment: If i try to add a different color to the .title-heading tag in css then it overrides the dark mode toggle, because the variance are only added to the body

Comment: I want to add a different color (green) to the .title-heading tag in light mode and have it switch to white in dark mode. rather than having all the titles blue like all the other fonts on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use   combinator to select children of `body` in light and dark separately.

[More about   combinator in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

This way, you can customize how they should look like in each color mode.

Example

```
body.light .title-heading {
  color: green;
}

body.dark .title-heading {
  color: white;
}
```

This example makes the `.title-heading` has `color: green` in light mode and `color: white` in dark mode.

You can use this approach to add customized styling for other elements all by CSS.

Hope this will help!